# How do I prove the general integral function?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If I assume $f$ is any real measurable function and $g$ integrable function. Now, let $\alpha, \beta \in R$ such that $\alpha \leq f \leq \beta $ $a.e.$. I want to prove that there exists $\gamma$ with $\alpha \leq \gamma \leq \beta$  such that $\int f|g|dx = \gamma\int |g|dx$. How I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g$ is not zero. Set $$ \gamma = \frac{\int f|g|}{\int |g|}.$$

Then prove $\alpha \leq \gamma \leq \beta$.

Comment: I think you wanted to say "suppose $\int \lvert g \rvert \neq 0$".

Comment: first you can prove $\alpha\int_E|g|\leq\int_E f|g|\leq\beta\int_E|g|$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I try to do this by using Intermediate Value Theorem, however I have problem, that is the Lebesgue integral need not be continuous.

Comment: $\gamma \int |g|\ dx$ is a continuous function of $\gamma$.